# How to get Pixel data \ Pixel buffer from a window and extract RGB?

Tags: c++, rgb, pixel

I'm drawing text (textOut) and Rectangles on my window...
and I would like to get the RGB buffer from it...
How can I do it?

Comment: You would probably just render into an off-screen bitmap to begin with. [Device contexts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/device-contexts) covers the fundamentals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 options:

First, you can use GetPixel(). I used it a lot. It works fine:

```
COLORREF GetPixel(
  HDC hdc, 
  int nXPos, 
  int nYPos
);
```

With our days processors picking up even a rect using this function may work in certain cases.

Second, you can copy contents of the screen into a bitmap. After that you can place it in clipboard, process with your code, etc. The core function there is:

```
BOOL BitBlt(
  _In_  HDC hdcDest,
  _In_  int nXDest,
  _In_  int nYDest,
  _In_  int nWidth,
  _In_  int nHeight,
  _In_  HDC hdcSrc,
  _In_  int nXSrc,
  _In_  int nYSrc,
  _In_  DWORD dwRop
);
```

I can post more detailed snippet if this is needed.

```
// Pick up the DC.
HDC hDC = ::GetDC(m_control);

// Pick up the second DC.
HDC hDCMem = ::CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);

// Create the in memory bitmap.
HBITMAP hBitmap = ::CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, bmp_size_x, bmp_size_y);

// Put bitmat into the memory DC. This will make it functional.
HBITMAP hBmpOld = (HBITMAP)::SelectObject(hDCMem, hBitmap);

// Clear the background.
HBRUSH hBkgr = ::CreateSolidBrush(props.bkgr_brush);
RECT bitmap_rect = { 0, 0, bmp_size_x, bmp_size_y };
::FillRect(hDCMem, &bitmap_rect, hBkgr);
::DeleteObject(hBkgr);

// Do the job.
::BitBlt(hDCMem, margins_rect.left, margins_rect.top,
    size_to_copy_x, size_to_copy_y, hDC,
    screen_from_x, screen_from_y, SRCCOPY);
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the response, yes can you post more detailed snippet? this is really new to me....

Comment: Kirill Kobelev, after running the code i get inside hMemDC element : error: expression cannt be evaluated.

i think i got something wrong with the size parameters,
margins_rect.left, margins_rect.top from where i get these?

when i'm creating the hBitamp its suppose to be the size of the hDC or it can be smaller?

how to evaluate the screen sizes?

thanks,

Comment: Please, do not take this piece of code literally. It just shows the right sequence of the function calls. Look the description of the params in MSDN for each function and update accordingly. I used this code, it works.