# Rust screenshot via windows, keep getting old data

Tags: windows, winapi, rust

Sorry if this has been answered somewhere but i've been trying to look for similar questions but have yet to find something that works for me.

Im trying to get pixel data from a specific window using the windows crate. My code looks like this:

```
        let handle = FindWindowA(None, "Some Title");
        let screen = GetDC(handle);
        let dst_screen = CreateCompatibleDC(screen);
        let captured_hbmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(screen, 100, 100);
        let hbmp_replace = SelectObject(dst_screen, captured_hbmp);
        
        BitBlt(
            dst_screen,
            0,
            0,
            100,
            100,
            screen,
            0,
            0,
            SRCCOPY,
        );
        
        let mut vec :Vec<u8> = vec![0; 100 * 100 * 4];
        
        
        GetBitmapBits(
            captured_hbmp,
            100 * 100 * 4,
            vec.as_mut_ptr() as *mut c_void
        );
        
        ReleaseDC(handle, screen);
        SelectObject(dst_screen, hbmp_replace);
        DeleteDC(dst_screen);
        DeleteObject(captured_hbmp);

        return vec;
```

Whenever i read the values in vec, it contains old data (seconds, minutes and even hours old data). Im guessing this is due to me not cleaning up correctly but i cant for the life of me understand where.

Any ideas?

Comment: See [screen capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/screen-capture) and [New Ways to do Screen Capture](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2019/09/16/new-ways-to-do-screen-capture/). If you can, use this interface instead.

Comment: @IInspectable Doesnt that require user interaction? If so, its not a viable solution for what im trying to do. Thanks for the tip though!

Comment: You can create GraphicsCaptureItem from a display, a window, or a visual: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.capture.graphicscaptureitem

Comment: @SimonMourier Seems like it only works without user interaction, if the window is a child to the process; which it isnt in my case.

Comment: "get pixel data from a specific window" I suggest you could try to use [GetPixel function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getpixel). You could refer to the thread:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13335113/how-to-get-pixel-data-pixel-buffer-from-a-window-and-extract-rgb.

Comment: @jea `GetPixel` is the **absolute** slowest way to read pixel data. And it fails for windows that are partially/fully occluded. Are you *"- MSFT"* folks on a race to the bottom? Consistently low quality contributions sure make it look like that.